# New Chromium Update Messes Up Background Adding Strange Lines

Tags: css, reactjs, google-chrome, tailwind-css, chromium

Recently I have created my website and it was all good until yesterday's chromium update. My website was looking like below:

[image: Working Website]

To render such background I'm using following code (tailwind, nextjs, react):

```js
    return (
        <html lang="en" className="!scroll-smooth">
            <body className={`${montserrat.className} pt-28 sm:pt-36 bg-gray-300 dark:bg-devil`}>
                <div className="bg-[#fbe2e3] dark:bg-[#671f91a8] absolute top-[1rem] -z-10 right-[11rem] h-[31.25rem] w-[31.25rem] rounded-full blur-[10rem] sm:w-[68.75rem]"></div>
                <div className="bg-[#dbd7fb] dark:bg-[#48457c] absolute top-[9rem] -z-10 left-[-35rem] h-[31.25rem] w-[50rem] rounded-full blur-[10rem] sm:w-[68.75rem] md:left-[-33rem] lg:left-[-28rem] xl:left-[-15rem] 2xl:left-[-5rem]"></div>

                <ThemeContextProvider>
                    <ActiveSectionContextProvider>
                        <Header />
                        {children}
                        <Footer />

                        <Toaster
                            position="top-right"
                            containerStyle={{
                                top: "5rem",
                            }}
                        />
                        <ThemeSwitch />
                    </ActiveSectionContextProvider>
                </ThemeContextProvider>
            </body>
        </html>
    )
```

And after last chromium update without any code change my website bg looks like this...

[image: Bugged Background]

Does anyone have any idea if this is chromium bug or if I can possibly fix it somehow? I have tried adjusting width to 100% etc. but it has no effect on those lines as those appear only when using blurred bg's, if there is solid bg lines are invisible.

Comment: Seems like it got confirmed as real bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1500021

Answer (score 0):

Adding the code below to each div with blur effect is fixing this issue.

```js
style={{ transform: "translate3d(0,0,0)" }}
```